# PHP to coldfusion Apple Signing and Zipping a Pass (Wallet Passkit)

Tags: java, php, coldfusion, wallet, passkit

how to do Apple Signing and Zipping a Pass coupon (Wallet Passkit) in coldfusion. i was googling but did not find any helpful source.

i only found this link but this guy also stuck looking for help..
[Link](http://themecode11.blogspot.com/2015/05/java-how-would-i-extract-public-and.html)

if some one know **JAVA jar** file which can use it will be really big help.

If some already did that please share knowledge.

***In PHP this is what im doing same think in need in COLDFUSION.***
*kind of stuck*

```
   //load .p12 certificate
$PKCS12 = file_get_contents($Certificates['Certificate']);
$certs = array();
if(openssl_pkcs12_read($PKCS12, $certs, $Certificates['CertPassword']) == true)
  {
    $certdata = openssl_x509_read($certs['cert']);
    $privkey = openssl_pkey_get_private($certs['pkey'], $Certificates['CertPassword']);
  }

//sign file hashes with AppleWWDRCA certificate
openssl_pkcs7_sign($ManifestPath, $SignaturePath, $certdata, $privkey, array(), PKCS7_BINARY | PKCS7_DETACHED, $Certificates['AppleWWDRCA']);
$ManifestSignature = file_get_contents($SignaturePath);
$ManifestSignatureDER = PEM2DER($ManifestSignature);

//put files (and strings as files) in a zip archive
$ZIP = new ZipArchive();
$ZIP->open($PKPassPath, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
$ZIP->addFromString('signature', $ManifestSignatureDER);
$ZIP->addFromString('manifest.json', $Manifest); 
$ZIP->addFromString('pass.json', $JSON);
foreach($ImageFiles as $ImagePath)
  {
    $ImageName = basename($ImagePath);
    $ZIP->addFile($ImagePath, $ImageName);
  }
$ZIP->close();

//load pass data und delete temp files (if debug mode is off)
$Pass['data'] = file_get_contents($PKPassPath);
$Pass['size'] = filesize($PKPassPath);
$Pass['name'] = $PassName;




 function echoPass($Pass)
  {
    //send http headers and zip archive content to client
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.apple.pkpass');
    header('Content-length: '.$Pass['size']);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$Pass['name'].'.pkpass"');
    echo $Pass['data'];

  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Before this gets closed as too broad/off topic (request for tool), try searching for "java passkit". Should return a few java libraries like https://github.com/drallgood/jpasskit . Haven't used it, but it looks like it does what's needed. Might also be able to use openssl via cfexecute. Then build a zip file with cfzip.

Comment: Thank you soo much i checked your given link.  i was having so many issues to compile while compiling.

Comment: Probably simpler to download the jar from maven (or you could use Eclipse and Maven to compile). http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22de.brendamour%22

Comment: @Ageax thankyouso much for your response i was dam happy after looking jar file this is what im looking..... but after unzip file i found it is not compiled some one uploaded un complied all .java files in side jar ...

Comment: You just downloaded the wrong jar ;-) One is .java sources, the other is the compiled jar with the .class files:  http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=de/brendamour/jpasskit/0.0.9/jpasskit-0.0.9.jar

Comment: man you are ** AWESOME ** just download it did not use it so far but thank you so much.. im writing code to use is but i wanted to say thank you!

Comment: @Ageax one question that jar is working just having issue `org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BouncyCastleProvider` in source code `import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;` look like package not able i have download file from `https://www.bouncycastle.org/download/bcprov-jdk15on-159.jar` and deploy but still having this error can you help me to sort this issue ?

Comment: CF already includes bouncy castle.  You'd need to post a) some CF code b) error messages and c) what jars you're loading and how?